# search for string and print line containing that string in a very large file

Tags: python

Trying to search for a string (email address) and print the line it is found in within a 1.66 gig .dump file(ashley madison). If I change print (line) to print ('true'), i get true returned, so i know it is reading the file, but when I try to print the line, python crashes with no error. Please help. python 3.4 on windows vista  (rather than using a database and importing, I'm using this as a learning exercize for python)

```
import os

with open('aminno_member_email.dump', 'r', errors = 'ignore')as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if 'email@address.com' in line:
            #print ('true')
            print (line)
```

Comment: My preliminary guess is some kind of encoding issue (ASCII vs UTF-8). Can you add the argument `encoding='utf-8'` in the `open()` call? And maybe `print(repr(line))`? Or maybe the lines are very long for some reason and it's having trouble printing them to the console? Have you tried writing each of the matching lines as output to a new file?

Comment: I tried your suggestions of utf-8 and print(repr(line)) and it still crashes.

Comment: How about `type(line)` and `len(line)`? It does take a significant amount of time to process, correct?

Comment: I was able to get a result by writing to a file...and it created a .97 mb text file, so i guess the lines are very large? best way to solve this issue?

Comment: Yeah, the console probably isn't happy with trying to display nearly a million characters in one go. Open the text file and Ctrl+F for your search string?

Comment: Yeah, I did that and found the particular email address in there once, but I know it's in the larger file twice. I guess i need to put in a for i: before writing, just wondered if there's a way to print x number of bytes before and after the string hit. or am I too hard-headed in trying to force it to print in console?

Comment: In that case, I'd say it wrote both lines to the file. ~500KB is still too much for the console to print in one line. I'll add a different solution to my answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a method for printing small snippets instead of the whole line. Try it on your ~1MB result file.

Comment: The credit card transactions are CSV files and contain better data than the member details. Textpad does a pretty good job searching across files and returning all hits in a single document. For the member data, installing MySQL is quick and simple. Depending on your computer, importing all the dump files can take hours to days. But once you have the data in MySQL, you can find individual records better than through text search. Or try Swiss File Knife if you don't want to go the MySQL route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, each line of that file is very long (to the tune of nearly a million characters, as you found). Most consoles are not set up to handle that sort of thing, so writing that line to a text file is your best bet. You can then open the file in a text editor or word processor and use its search function to locate areas of interest.

To display your search string with some characters of surrounding text, you can use a regular expression.

```
import re
...
# replace this:
'''
    if 'email@address.com' in line:
        #print ('true')
        print (line)
'''
# with this:
    print(*re.findall(r'(.{0,10}email@address\.com.{0,10})', line), sep='\n')
```

That will print each match with up to `10` characters before and after the search string, separated by a newline.

Example:

```
>>> print(*re.findall(r'(.{0,10}str.{0,10})', 'hello this is a string with text and it is very strong stuff'), sep='\n')
this is a string with t
t is very strong stuff
```

Comment: I added the following and got it to print the huge lie with the searched string:

Comment: with open ('damn.txt', 'w') as file:

Answer (score -2):

Open the file as stream instead and read from the stream instead of loading the entire file to RAM. Use [**io** from the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html).

```
with io.open('aminno_member_email.dump', 'r') as file:
    ...
```

Comment: Iterating over a file with `for line in searchfile:` doesn't load the entire file into RAM. That's the whole point of that approach.